# How can I turn multiple jpegs into a Dicom file?

Tags: c#, dicom, fo-dicom, dicomweb

I'm currently working on a c# project where I manipulate videos/images and turn them into Dicom files.
For the moment I'm able to create a Dicom file from a single image. But now I would like to store multiple images into a single Dicom file.
Can someone help me please ?

I tried to convert multiple Dicom files containing each a .jpg image into a single Dicom file, but it's not what I wanted.

Comment: 1) From tags, it seems you want to achieve this using fo-dicom. What is the role of dicomweb tag here? 2) You said you converted single frame. Please post that code here.

Comment: Please refer to the code sample in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57040845/5779732) question. It creates the multiframe DICOM image from bmp/jpg. The bug in that code is corrected in answer below that question. I hope that helps you.